# Search Some Part in Dictionary key and Update Its value

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
  Dim List As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)

List.Add("krunal", 21.65)
List.Add("krunal SQL", 22.65)
List.Add("krunal Ora", 23.65)
List.Add("Spaghetti alla puttanesca ", 24.65)
List.Add("Spaghetti alla gricia ", 25.65)
List.Add("Spaghetti ale vongole", 26.65)
List.Add("Spaghetti Bolognese", 27.65)

If List.Where(Function(x) x.Key.Contains("SQL")).Any() Then
    List.Item("SQL") =2
End If
```

and update value for find Part?
How to Search And Update it?

Answer (score 3):

To *update* the dictionary you'd need to access it via the *actual* key:

```
For Each key In List.Keys.Where(Function(x) x.Contains("SQL"))
    List(key) = 2
Next
```

Comment: don't Use ***For Loop*** I have 100000 record so its too much Difficult Job. To Find and update

Comment: @krunalmodi Well, you can't index a dictionary on whether it _contains_ an arbitrary string, so I don't see an alternative.  What do you mean by "difficult job"?  It's certainly not hard to _code_.  Is it a _measurable_ performance problem or are you just concerned it "might be"?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is along the right lines;

You can iterate over the `KeyValuePair`s that match the key but you then need to find the key of the items that match to reference back to your list:

```
    For Each matchingKeyValuePair In List.Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Key.Contains("SQL"))
        List(matchingKeyValuePair.Key) = 99.99
    Next
```

You can also just iterate over the 'Keys` if that is all you are searching:

```
For Each matchingKey In List.Keys.Where(Function(key) key.Contains("SQL"))
     List(matchingKey) = 99.99
Next
```

Note that instead of

`.Contains("SQL")` which is case sensitive.

You might actually want:

`.IndexOf("SQL", 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1` which is not

Comment: don't Use ***For Loop*** I have 100000 record so its too much Difficult Job. To Find and update

Comment: The For Loop is only looping over the keys that match your criteria, not the complete dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a `string` as a key in a `Dictionary` is case sensitive. This means that if you add `"SQL"` it would only match `"SQL"` and not `"sql"` or `"Sql"` when you do a direct lookup in the dictionary by indexer or use the `Contains(string key)` method. I mention this because it would be easy to accidentally add multiple items to the dictionary where the casing of each items key is the only difference without getting an error. You will have to guard against this or convert your keys to upper or lower case and then use an object as the value which contains both the number and the correct casing of the item you are storing.

The method `string.Contains` is also case sensitive. If you want to perform a case insensitive search you could change your code to use [string.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
For Each key In List.Keys.Where(Function(x) x.IndexOf("SQL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    List(key) = 2 ' use key as the indexer
Next
```

[From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx):

> #### OrdinalIgnoreCase
>
> Compare strings using ordinal (binary) sort rules and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.

---

#### Edit

Based on the last comment it seems the OP wants something faster than a loop due to the size of the dictionary. The only thing I can see that you can do is to use the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) and multi-thread it. Placing the check inside the method body or outside in the collection passed to the ForEach depends on the expected number of hits/true conditions where you need an update. You would have to test it a couple of times with sample data that matches what will be expected in your actual environment.

```
Parallel.ForEach(List.Keys.Where(Function(x) x.IndexOf("SQL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList(), Sub(currentKey)
        List(currentKey) = 2 ' use key as the indexer
    End Sub)
```

Or this

```
Parallel.ForEach(List.Keys, Sub(currentKey)
        If currentKey.IndexOf("SQL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) Then
            List(currentKey) = 2 ' use key as the indexer
        End If
    End Sub)
```

You might not see a difference but I would test both ways with your data and measure which one is faster. To measure time start to end use a `StopWatch` instance.

Comment: don't Use ***For Loop*** I have 100000 record so its too much Difficult Job. To Find and update

Comment: @krunalmodi - You never stated that in your question. I have added an alternative to speed up the loop.